# No audio in Ubuntu 16.04, Intel Corporation Device a171 (rev 31) Audio device

Tags: 16.04, sound, hp, intel

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 in my HP Omen laptop, but I am not able to hear any audio !

```
srivatsan@srivatsan:~$ lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device a171 (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 8259
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 135
    Memory at b4428000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at b4410000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

It seems that the Audio device in my laptop is Intel Corporation Device a171 (rev 31). I can see from [this link that this audio device is not supported by Ubuntu](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Matrix:Vendor-Intel). Am I true in saying so ? If so what is the solution to fix the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by resetting the default audio configuration according to http://www.utdream.org/post.cfm/resetting-pulseaudio-on-ubuntu-13-04-new-sound-card

- Remove alsa-related softwares and pulseaudio :

sudo apt purge alsa*

sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio indicator-sound

- Reinstall them :

sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio indicator-sound

- Then type :

sudo alsa force-reload

- Then reboot.

At start, open the pulseaudio volume control (from the Whisker menu or typing "pavucontrol" in a terminal). Click on the **top-right arrow** (that I had not noticed at first sight) to the "Configuration" tab and select "Stereo Analogic Duplex".

Now move to the first tab ("Lecture" on my french release, might be "Play" on an english one) and unmute the output by clicking the Headphone icon.

Sound came back right after this click (no need for a reboot).